# Relative link and smooth scroll to it on load

Tags: jquery, html

A have relative links `/info/here#point-reach`. When I click a link to it it goes to page /info/here and simultaneously takes to anchor #point-reach. Is it possible to go to this `/info/here#point-reach` link from other page and smoothly from the top get to this anchor? 
Code I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready( function(){            
    var getLink = window.location.hash
    setTimeout(function(){               
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(getLink).offset().top }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
})


<a id="package-5-view"></a>
                <input type="radio" id="package-5" class="accordion-section" hidden="">
                    <div class="section dark package-description">
                        <div class="animated-content">
                            <div class="wrapper fbox jc-sb">
                                <div class="two-five">
                                    <p style="margin-bottom: 40px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in vix inermis principes, vis soluta definiebas no. Sea cu laboramus comprehensam, homero ullamcorper vis te. Eam id insolens antiopam, pri an nihil libris facilisis. Perpetua efficiantur per ne. Ne per simul tritani offendit, eu quo atqui virtute deserunt.
                                        <ul class="list-style">
                                            <li>Швидкі результати тесту</li>
                                            <li>Зручне, просте і швидке проходоження тесту</li>
                                            <li>Приємна ціна!</li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your html too?

Comment: I dont think it will help you much, code is above.

Comment: This should work. what is the issue? Have you added this script in head for all pages?

Comment: @Jai, added -document ready-. 
http://nikolad0.bget.ru/ru/genetictests
Second block with huge rhombus they link to target.

Comment: Now it throws to anchor. without smooth sliding to it.

Answer (score 1):

This script should be added in the head of each page or put in a js file and include that file in the head/body and `setTimeout()` method isn't needed because that waits for one sec after dom ready but page jumps on the link and the smooth scroll effect doesn't show up:

```
// file.js <---include this file at a common place which is available for all pages.
$(document).ready( function(){            
    var getLink = window.location.hash;
    if(getLink){
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(getLink).offset().top }, 1000);
    }
})
```

This will ensure if we have a hash in the url and `document.ready` block ensures that we have our element to work on. So, the idea is make a common js file which can be added for each html file or *say different urls* and if the url contains any hash value it'll run for that.

Comment: Then you don't need the `setTimeout` method, that is quite late for that.

Comment: agree. Thats why I stuck . . .

Comment: Not helping... the same result.

Comment: Phalcon php... or what?

Comment: Okay do you see any error in the browser's console?

Comment: added an answer, if interested see the work http://nikolad0.bget.ru/genetictests and click huge rhombuses from the next from top section. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
If we pass Div id which is available in page then directly it will go on that div id.
To avoid this just pass some special character in hash

eg. Just add !(or any symbol) after hash so i will be work fine.
/info/here#!point-reach

$(document).ready( function(){            
        var getLink = document.location.hash.substr(1);
         if(getLink.indexOf("!") != -1){
                var rel = hash.replace("!","");                
            setTimeout(function(){      
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#'+rel).offset().top
            }, 1000);
         }, 1000);`enter code here`
        }
})
```

Comment: No use to it... Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.ready, I used window.load. So the first action we get on top of the window, then with a delay we get to our anchor.
So here is the code that helped (nevermind some other code adds):

```
$(window).load(function() {
       $(this).scrollTop(0)
        var getLink = window.location.hash;
        if(getLink){
            $(getLink).next().prop('checked', 'checked')
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(getLink).offset().top }, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```